# Spring Boot Package to war: Tests fail

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, lightadmin

I'm attempting to package my Spring Boot app as a war file, so that I can use [LightAdmin](http://lightadmin.org/) (which has [a limitation](http://lightadmin.org/getting-started/spring-boot/) of only working for Spring Boot apps using traditional war packaging).

I'm trying to run the `mvn package` goal, but it fails at the test phase with this error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.528 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-11T15:09:35-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/393M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project vote: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.loadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:252)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateOneArg(ReflectionUtils.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.createProviderInCurrentClassloader(ForkedBooter.java:230)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:199)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.loadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:244)
[ERROR] ... 5 more
```

here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>lightadmin-nexus-releases</id>
            <url>http://lightadmin.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- temporary in memory H2 DB for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.191</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Testing packages-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--the administration panel is powered by LightAdmin-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lightadmin</groupId>
            <artifactId>lightadmin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--need to add tomcat starter for war files (lightadmin needs a war file)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--Used to generate a *.war file (needed to run LightAdmin-->
            <!--http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!--
            Front End Build plugins
            https://medium.com/@l1ambda/webpack-a-spring-boot-app-with-instant-page-refresh-5d051a09d26f
            -->
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build the front end -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>run</argument>
                        <argument>build</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <!--<workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>-->
                    <workingDirectory>.</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Copy the front end into the static folder for JARs-->
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static/assets</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/frontend/dist</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Did you try adding surefire plugin to your pom?

Comment: @techtabu Thank you sir! That was the solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the maven surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```